# getting filename attached to a record in AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

how to get a filename attached to  a record in AX 2012...
e.g., I have some table named table1 in which I have attached a file with each record.

Now, i want to write a job to fetch the name of files attached to a particular record in a table.

I got it working as

```
static void CheckAttacheddocu(Args _args)
{
   Dev_Attachment objAttachment;
    DocuRef obj_docuRef;
    ;
   select  objAttachment
      where objAttachment.AttachmentId == "001";

    select obj_docuRef
        where obj_docuRef.RefRecId == objAttachment.RecId;
    info(obj_docuRef.Name);
}
```

Comment: How did you attach the files?

Comment: I have attached files using standard document management in AX 2012. i.e, using document handling form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/docuref.path.aspx) on the [DocuRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/docuref.aspx) table.

```
select obj_docuRef
    where obj_docuRef.RefRecId == objAttachment.RecId;
info(obj_docuRef.path());
```